# Search by repository name and substring of login

Tags: github-api

This will return my desired results

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=myRepoName%20user:myUserName`

This will **not**

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=myRepoName%20user:myUser`

How can I use the Github API to search for a known repo name but only a partial login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible currently. What's your use case for this? If you'd like to share more information about why you need such an ability, please reach out: https://github.com/contact.